# RESTful API, http get from couple of keys

Tags: node.js, express, http, get

I'm new with node.js and I am building a RESTful API.
I have the following data:

```
const matches = [ 
{
home_team: "Sutton United",
home_score: 0,
away_team: "Arsenal",
away_score: 0,
tournament: "fa",
start_time: "Monday 20th February 2017"
},
{
home_team: "Arsenal",
home_score: 0,
away_team: "Chelsea",
away_score: 0,
tournament: "fa",
start_time: "Monday 20th February 2017"
}
];
```

and I'm trying to get a response of all matches a team participate, no matter if it is home or away. 
Therefore, when I'm lookin for 'Arsenal', I want to get both matches.
My code looks like that:

```
app.get('/api/matches/:home_team'||'/api/matches/:away_team', (req, res) => {
const match = matches.find(c => (c.home_team === req.params.home_team || c.away_team === req.params.away_team))
if (!match) res.status(404).send('The match with the given id was not found');
res.send(match);});
```

which doesn't work the way I want.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use filter instead of find:

```
app.get('/api/matches/:team', (req, res) => {
const match = matches.filter(c => (c.home_team === req.params.team || c.away_team === req.params.team));
if (!match) 
   res.status(404).send('The match with the given id was not found');
res.send(match);
});
```

Comment: @Eusebius Also use one route and compare with it. Check my updated answer.